# Solve for a and b in n = a + (a+1) + (a+2) + … + b

Tags: c

Given *n*, how can we find non-negative integers *a* and *b* such that *n* = *a* + (*a*+1) + (*a*+2) + … + *b* using simple C code?

This is what I have written so far.

```
int main()
{
    int a, b, n;
    n=0;
    printf("Enter the value of n:");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    n = a+(a+1)+(a+2)+b;

    for(int i=a; i<=b; i++)
    {
        a=1;
        b=8;
       if (a<=i && i<=b)
       printf("%d", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you know about the formula for finding the sum of [arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression)? This will give you a one-two lines solution.

Comment: I think you are misusing the word "interval". You just want to solve the equation.

Comment: @RaymondChen I believe there might be more than one solution. So my "one-two" lines is actually "four-five" :)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show some examples of input and expected output. BTW your code is wrong at least because `a` is never initialized. In C local variables arew not initialized by default with zero, their content is indetermined.

Comment: If task is, given a number n, to find two integers a and b such that n equals a + (a+1) + (a+2) + … + b, then you need to do some thinking about mathematics first. Unfortunately, this may not be a problem suitable for a student who has only just learned about simple loops. Unless perhaps a “brute-force” solution is intended, by iterating on potential values of a and b, requiring three nested loops.

Comment: The task is: For a given number n find the interval [a,b] so that the sum of  a + (a+1) + (a+2) + … + b equals n.

Comment: @user9778258: An interval is a set of points—the interval [a, b] is the set of all x such that a ≤ x and x ≤ b. In the domain of real numbers, it contains infinitely many numbers, if a < b. But your actual problem is just to find two numbers, a and b. To mathematicians, there is an isomorphism between the intervals [a, b] and the pairs (a, b), assuming suitable constraints and relationships, so saying you want to find the interval [a, b] is not incorrect; it is equivalent in a sense. But to many of the Stsck Overflow participants, it would be clearer to them to say the task is to find a and b.

Comment: @user9778258 the goal is definitively to find the couples (a,b) satisfying the formula. I put an answer with a proposal giving them (and a derived checking this is right)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supposing *n* and *a* cannot be negative :

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* n == a + (a+1) + (a+2) + ... + (a + m) == a*(m+1) + m*(m+1)/2
   a = (n/(m+1)) - m/2;
   b = (a + m) */

int main(void)
{
  int n;

  if ((scanf("%d", &n) != 1)|| (n < 0))
    puts("invalid value");
  else {
    for (int m = 0; ; ++m) {
      int a = (n/(m+1)) - m/2;

      if (a < 0)
        break;

      /* check no round problem */
      if ((a*(m+1) + m*(m+1)/2) == n)
        printf("a=%d b=%d (m=%d)\n", a, a+m, m);

      if (a == 0)
        break;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and executions :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wextra f.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
0
a=0 b=0 (m=0)
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
1
a=1 b=1 (m=0)
a=0 b=1 (m=1)
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
2
a=2 b=2 (m=0)
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
10
a=10 b=10 (m=0)
a=1 b=4 (m=3)
a=0 b=4 (m=4)
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
123
a=123 b=123 (m=0)
a=61 b=62 (m=1)
a=40 b=42 (m=2)
a=18 b=23 (m=5)
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

---

A version checking all is correct doing the formula, in case you trust on nothing ;-)

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* n == a + (a+1) + (a+2) + ... + (a + m) == a*(m+1) + m*(m+1)/2
   a = (n/(m+1)) - m/2;
   a == 0 => n == m*(m+1)/2 => 
   b = (a + m) */

int f(int a, int b)
{
  int r = 0;
  int m = 0;

  do {
    r += a+m;
  } while ((a + m++) != b);

  return r;
}

int main(void)
{
  int n;

  if ((scanf("%d", &n) != 1)|| (n < 0))
    puts("invalid value");
  else {
    for (int m = 0; ; ++m) {
      int a = (n/(m+1)) - m/2;

      if (a < 0)
        break;

      if ((a*(m+1) + m*(m+1)/2) == n)
        printf("a=%d b=%d (m=%d) : %s\n", a, a+m, m, (n == f(a, a+m)) ? "ok" : "KO");
      if (a == 0)
        break;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -g -pedantic -Wall -Wextra f.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
0
a=0 b=0 (m=0) : ok
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
1
a=1 b=1 (m=0) : ok
a=0 b=1 (m=1) : ok
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
2
a=2 b=2 (m=0) : ok
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
10
a=10 b=10 (m=0) : ok
a=1 b=4 (m=3) : ok
a=0 b=4 (m=4) : ok
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
123
a=123 b=123 (m=0) : ok
a=61 b=62 (m=1) : ok
a=40 b=42 (m=2) : ok
a=18 b=23 (m=5) : ok
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Comment: @LuisColorado you are wrong, I written `n == a + (a+1) + (a+2) + ... + (a + m)` (and also `b = (a + m) `) and I obviously did that to explain it is `a*(m+1) + m*(m+1)/2`. Before to say something is incorrect I encourage you to read better ;-) Note also the second version of my code checks the result is correct, a false premise producing a good result is not impossible but requires a second error masking the first error.

Comment: @LuisColorado where do you see a _m_ in the question ? there is no _m_ in the question.,I only introduced it to show the classic formula  1+2+3+...+m. I already see your answer, and it is wrong requiring to also enter _a_. I encourage you do do what you say and to take time to read the question and my answer ;-)

Comment: How can you continue like that ? As I said **I** decided to introduced _m_ and _again_ that to show the formula 1+2+3+...+m, and because the last element of the serial is named _b_ by the OP of course `a+m` is _b_. All of that is trivial,  really I do not understand your reaction, as I do not understand how you can say "_where do you see in the question that b must be the last term in the succession_" while this is explicitly indicated in the OP question both in the title and in the body!

Answer (score 0):

A possible way to solve this problem, without exploiting the known formula for arithmetic progression and "using simple C code" as asked by the OP (well, for some definition of *simple*), is to use a running total (or partial sum) while exploring the possible values of `a` and `b`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    // Instead of asking a value 'n', test all the values up to 128
    puts("    n    a    b\n-------------------");
    for (int n = 0; n <= 128; ++n)
    {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        int sum = 0;

        while ( a <= b  &&  b <= n )
        {
            if ( sum == n )
            {
                printf("%5d%5d%5d\n", n, a, b);     
            }
            if ( sum < n )
            {
                // Add the next highest term to the sum
                ++b;      
                sum += b;
            }
            else
            {
                // Remove the former lowest term from the sum
                sum -= a;
                ++a;
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

Testable [HERE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zQwsp9frnd3e4OFk).